# FFmpeg same Filename for output but without extension with python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

i'm kinda noob with Python but i managed to make this code to encode multiple videos files from a folder to H265, everything woks fine exept for the output name.

Actually the output name keep the old file extension with the new one like this "MyMovie.mov.mp4" and i want it to be named like this "MyMovie.mp4" is there any way to exclude the original file extension from the output file?

```
import os, sys, re

input_folder= '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos'
output_folder= '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/X265' 
quality_setting = '30'
file_type = 'mp4

my_suffixes = (".mp4", ".mov", ".mkv", ".avi", ".ts", ".flv", ".webm", ".wmv", ".mpg", ".m4v", ".f4v")

from pathlib import Path
Path(output_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

for filename in os.listdir(my_folder):
   if (filename.endswith(my_suffixes)):
       cmd = !ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -hwaccel cuvid -i "$input_folder/{filename}" -metadata comment="X265-QF$quality_setting-AAC" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset:v slow -rc vbr -cq $quality_setting -c:a aac -b:a 160k "$output_folder/{filename}.$file_type"
```

Ps: This code is used on Google Colab that's why i need this with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way i used rpartition to cut the file extension

```
cmd = !ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -hwaccel cuvid -i "$input_folder/{filename}" -metadata comment="X265-QF$quality_setting-AAC" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset:v slow -rc vbr -cq $quality_setting -c:a aac -b:a 160k "$output_folder/{filename.rpartition('.')[0]}.$file_type"
```

Answer (score 0):

In you for-loop you check if filename ends with one of the extensions listed above. So filename contains something like `output.mp4` then in `cmd` you add `.$file_type` to the end of your command which is set to `.mp4`. I think you should remove that last part so you will only have the extension contained in filename.

Comment: The problem with this is that HEVC/H 265 only support a few container like ".mp4" or ".mkv". So i can't keep the original extension it will cause some error if for example i put a ".avi" file.

Comment: Okay so just remove `.$file_type` at the end. You're adding it yourself.